# NSDictionary key comparison fails

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

I am dealing a very basic problem, I have two dictionary keys I need to compare but when I do it doesn't give me correct answer, somehow I am failing to create the logic.

So I have this in a plist array of dictionaries and json array comming from server
I want to compare them if event exist in plist do certain thing if not do another thing;

**PROBLEM:**
According to my logic if two events in plist are equal to other two events comming from server if logic should be printed per for each dictionary coming from server , so in this case 2 times total , but in my code it is printed 4 times. basically it is satisfying the condition every single time.

**NSLOG:**

```
evreka find the id
evreka find the id
evreka find the id
evreka find the id
```

**SOURCE:**
in a plist;

```
createList (
        {
        "end_date" = "2013-07-24";
        ends = "13:07:00";
        "event_id" = 173;
        "event_name" = Static;
        location = Asdad;
        "root_folder" = "dadapof@gmail.com";
        "start_date" = "2013-07-24";
        starts = "13:07:00";
        "user_id" = 13;
    },
        {
        "end_date" = "2013-07-25";
        ends = "13:08:00";
        "event_id" = 174;
        "event_name" = "Event Delete";
        location = Asdsad;
        "root_folder" = "dadapof@gmail.com";
        "start_date" = "2013-07-25";
        starts = "13:08:00";
        "user_id" = 13;
    }
)
```

This comming from server

```
responseobj (
        {
        "end_date" = "2013-07-24";
        ends = "13:07:00";
        "event_id" = 173;
        "event_name" = Static;
        location = Asdad;
        "root_folder" = "dadapof@gmail.com";
        "start_date" = "2013-07-24";
        starts = "13:07:00";
        "user_id" = 13;
    },
        {
        "end_date" = "2013-07-25";
        ends = "13:08:00";
        "event_id" = 174;
        "event_name" = "Event Delete";
        location = Asdsad;
        "root_folder" = "dadapof@gmail.com";
        "start_date" = "2013-07-25";
        starts = "13:08:00";
        "user_id" = 13;
    }
)
```

**CODE:**

Comparison code;

```
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataPath]){
        createList= [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:dataPath];
        NSLog(@"createList %@",createList);
        NSLog(@"responseobj %@",responseObj);


        //compare plist and response object
        for (int i=0; i<[responseObj count]; i++) {
            NSDictionary *dataDict = [responseObj objectAtIndex:i];

            NSString *event_name =[dataDict objectForKey:@"event_name"];
            //NSString *event_id =[dataDict objectForKey:@"event_id"];

            BOOL eventExistInPlist=NO;


            for (int j=0; j<[createList count]; j++) {
                NSDictionary *createDict = [createList objectAtIndex:i];

                //NSString *create_id =[createDict objectForKey:@"event_id"];
                NSNumber *create_id =[createDict objectForKey:@"event_id"];

                if ([[dataDict objectForKey:@"event_id"] isEqual:[createDict objectForKey:@"event_id"]]) {
               // if (create_id==event_id) {
                    NSLog(@"evreka find the id");
```

**What I have tried:**
I have tried to compare them as strings(isEqualtoString), numbers(==) and isEqual: method , they have all failed.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: First off, make things simpler and less confusing by extracting the value of `[dataDict objectForKey:@"event_id"]` outside the inner loop and holding it in a local variable.  (I see you did this and commented it out.  Why?)  And why are there no NSLogs of the values you're fetching -- they would probably identify your problem quickly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In

```
 NSDictionary *createDict = [createList objectAtIndex:i];
                                                      ^----- HERE
```

you are using the wrong index, it should be `j` instead of `i` for the inner loop.

Answer (score 1):

Martin R's answer is where your issue is. I would change your logic though to include Objective-C fast enumeration instead of the standard for ++ loop. I also separated out the second for loop into a BOOL method for easier reading

```
for (NSDictionary *dataDict in responseObj) {
    NSString *event_name =[dataDict objectForKey:@"event_name"];
    if ([self matchFoundForEventId:event_name]) {
        NSLog(@"Match found");
    }
}

-(BOOL)matchFoundForEventId:(NSString *)eventId {
    for (NSDictionary *dataDict in createList) {
        NSString *createEvent = [dataDict objectForKey:@"event_id"];
        if ([eventId isEqualToString:createEvent]) {
            return YES;
        }
    }
    return NO;
}
```